# Give dynamic title to button and resize it without setting height constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I added a button to my view in viewcontroller and I gave it only positioning constraints (which are top space and leading space). In my button I added a set, an image and a title which is three four words. I have other views in the same horizontal row. I set their title and edge insets programmatically so both are aligned to center and title is just below the button.

How can I set its title dynamically so it will show full title?  I have already used sizeToFit function that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the size of your button title label using `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`, then set the `UIButton.frame` accordingly.

[Apple docs - boundingRectWithSize:options:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize:options:context:)

**Edit:**

[Autolayout resize button based on text and have textfield fill available space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226220/autolayout-resize-button-based-on-text-and-have-textfield-fill-available-space)

Comment: ma'am but I want to use autlolayout otherwise there are many other methods and setframe doesnt work in autolayout

Comment: will try it tomorrow and will upvote your anser if works